# Can I run multiple GRPC services on same port

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm working on `gRPC` and I want to run multiple services on same **port**

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
    .addService(new HelloServiceImpl())
    .addService(new ByeServiceImpl())
    .build();
```

Is this the right way to run multiple GRPC services on same port? Full code below.

**HelloWorld.proto**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;

package proto3.rpc;

message HelloRequest {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}

service HelloService {
    rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

**ByWorld.proto**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;

package proto3.rpc;

message ByeRequest {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;
}

message ByeResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}

service ByeService {
    rpc bye(ByeRequest) returns (ByeResponse);
}
```

**HelloServiceImpl.java**

```java
public class HelloServiceImpl extends HelloServiceImplBase{

    @Override
    public void hello(
        HelloRequest request,
        StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver){

        String greeting = new StringBuilder()
            .append("Hello, ")
            .append(request.getFirstName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(request.getLastName())
            .toString();

        HelloResponse helloResponse = HelloResponse.newBuilder()
            .setGreeting(greeting)
            .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(helloResponse);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();  
    }

}
```

**ByeServiceImpl.java**

```java
public class ByeServiceImpl extends ByeServiceImplBase{

    @Override
    public void bye(
        ByeRequest request,
        StreamObserver<ByeResponse> responseObserver){

        String greeting = new StringBuilder()
            .append("Bye, ")
            .append(request.getFirstName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(request.getLastName())
            .toString();

        ByeResponse byeResponse = ByeResponse.newBuilder()
            .setGreeting(greeting)
            .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(byeResponse);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();  
    }

}
```

**GrpcServer.java**

```java
public class GrpcServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
    .addService(new HelloServiceImpl())
    .addService(new ByeServiceImpl())
    .build();

        try {
            server.start();
            server.awaitTermination();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**GrpcClient.java**

```java
public class GrpcClient {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080)
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

        HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceBlockingStub stub
            = HelloServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);    

        HelloResponse helloResponse = stub.hello(HelloRequest.newBuilder()
            .setFirstName("Azeem")
            .setLastName("Haider")
            .build()
        );    

        System.out.println("Hello Service...");
        System.out.println(helloResponse.getGreeting());    

        ByeServiceGrpc.ByeServiceBlockingStub stubBye
            = ByeServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);    

        ByeResponse byeResponse = stubBye.bye(ByeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setFirstName("Azeem")
            .setLastName("Haider")
            .build()
        );    


        System.out.println("Bye Service...");
        System.out.println(byeResponse.getGreeting());    

        channel.shutdown(); 
    }

}
```

**OUPUT**

```
Hello Service...
Hello Azeem Haider

Bye Service...
Bye Azeem Haider
```

I know both **Services** files look very similar but this is just for example how we can run multi services on same **IP:PORT** I'm using this way is it a good way or is there any preferred way?

Comment: What is the problem? You can add as much services as you like, they will all run at the same port.

Comment: The question is how to run multiple services on the same port, but I do not see in your code where you create a server and add services.

Comment: @AnarSultanov Sorry, I forget to add this now I update the question. I'm just asking it is  a preferred way or not

Comment: @AzeemHaider Yes, this is a completely standard way of adding your services and starting a server, at least if you do not use any other framework in your application that can handle it for you (e.g. Spring Boot).

Comment: @AnarSultanov in future I planed to use **Google Guice** framework, any suggestions?

Comment: @AzeemHaider as far as I know, Google Guice does not have any additional features other than dependency injection, so I don’t think that this will have any impact. The only thing you are likely to do is create the singletons of your services and inject them where needed.

Comment: Yes because I only need **Dependency Injection** Thanks for the suggestion of **Singletons** approch

Answer (score 18):

Your usage is correct.   A **Server** listens on a socket, and dispatches to one or more **Services**.